# Blender UI - Pop-Up that will block script execution

Tags: python, interface

I wanted to know if it was possible, with blender UI tools, to make a pop up that will block script execution until user action. I haven't found my way yet. I know that Operators are called in an asynchronous manner, but there is many case where it could be usefull so I think i'm missing something.

Here is where I am so far:

```
import bpy


class MessageBox(bpy.types.Operator):
    
    bl_idname = 'ui.message_box'
    bl_label = ''
    
    text: bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name='text',
        default=''
        )
    
    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'LEFTMOUSE':
            return {'FINISHED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
    
    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'} 
    
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text=str(self.text))


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MessageBox)
    

def my_func():
    register()
    # doing stuff
    bpy.ops.ui.message_box('INVOKE_DEFAULT', text='Hello World!')
    # Wait for input
    # doing other stuff. 

my_func()
```

Any idea would be highly appreciated here.

Cheers!